# How to calculate Probabailty of (Null is true given Ho is rejected)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Given:

- $\alpha = 0.05$,
- $\beta = 0.10$,
- $p = 0.5$ (Prior probabailty of $H_0$)

How can we calculate $P(H_0 \text{ true} | H_0 \text{ rejected})$

Is it just $1 - \beta$?

I was thinking that maybe using Bayes rule:
$$P(H_0 \text{ true} | H_0 \text{ rejected}) = \frac{P(H_0 \text{ rejected} | H_0 \text{ true}) \cdot P(H_0 \text{ true})}{P(H_0 \text{ rejected})}$$

1. As $P(H_0 \text{ rejected} | H_0 \text{ true}) = \alpha$
2. $P(H_0 \text{ rejected}) = p(\text{true reject}) + p(\text{false reject}) = p(H_0 \text{ is truly rejected}) + p(H_0 \text{ is falsely rejected}) = p(\text{true positive}) + p(\text{false positive}) = (1−\beta) + \alpha$
3. $P(H_0 \text{ true}) = p(\text{prior probability of }H_0)$

Putting into the formula we get: $0.05(0.5)/(1-0.1)+0.05 = 0.026$

Is this right ?

Comment: NO. Frequentist statistics do not assign probabilities to hypothesis, so for an answer you need to go Bayesian. But look into *false discovery rates*

Comment: I was thinking that maybe using bayes rule:
P(Ho is true/ Ho is rejected) = P(Ho is rejected/ Ho is true)*P(Ho is true) / P(Ho is rejected)

1. As P(Ho is rejected/Ho is true) = alpha

2. P(Ho is rejected)  = p(true reject) + p(false reject)

= p(Ho is truly rejected) + p(Ho is falsely rejected)

= p(true positive) + p (false positive)

= (1−β) + α

3. P(Ho is true) = p (prior probability of Ho)

Putting into the formula we get:

= 0.05(0.5)/(1-0.1)+0.05
= 0.026

What do you think ?

Comment: Please add this as an edit to the post, then it will also enter a queue for review for reopening ...